# calculating limit of sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

$\mathbf {Question:}$ $(x_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers given by $ x_1 = 0$, $x_2$ = $\frac12$ and $x_{n+1} = \frac{(1+x_n+x_{n-1}^3)}{3}$. Find the limit of the sequence.

$\mathbf {My Attempt:}$ By applying limit on the given equation and by solving the polynomial I have got that possible values of $\lim \,x_n$ are - 1, $\frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2}$ and $\frac{-\sqrt{5} - 1}{2}$ . Since all the elements of the sequence are non negative $\lim \,x_n$ $\neq \frac{-\sqrt{5} - 1}{2}$. But I am not being able to decide between the other two possibilities. I have calculated first few terms of the sequence manually and have observed that the terms of the sequence are in the neighborhood of $\frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2}$. Thus it is my guess that $\lim \,x_n$ = $\frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2}$. But I am failing to prove this.

I have also got that $x_{n+1}\geq (x_n)^{\frac13}x_{n-1}$ using A.M. $\geq$ G.M. . But I don't know whether it is of any use or not.

Please guide me to solve this problem.

Thank You.

Comment: Hint: $(1+\frac 23+(\frac 23)^3)/3<\frac 23$ so you can disregard the limit $1$. Also from what I can see numerically $x_n\nearrow$ maybe we can also prove that.

Comment: @zwim Sorry, I couldn't follow your hint. Please explain it a little more.

Comment: For the increasing part, I have looked quickly but without success for now. For the limit, since $x_1,x_2<\frac 23$ then by induction $x_3<\frac 23$ and then $x_n<\frac 23$ for all $n$ (but you can as well prove it with $x_n<\ell=(\sqrt{5}-1)/2$).

Comment: Prove by induction that for the given initial conditions all items are less than $(\sqrt 5-1)/2$. That rules out 1 as a possible solution.

Comment: Hint: x_n is monotonic increasing and bounded above and hence convergent.

Comment: I got it. Thank you all.